# Angular - Why does clicking on a checkbox fire a change event for the parent selector in which the change event is bound to?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular-forms

So, I was just minding my own business on Gitter when I came across something interesting. Take a look at [this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-controlcontainer-formarray-iemzly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox.directive.ts).

It uses a custom directive that makes a custom checkbox component work with `ngModel`/`formControl` etc.

What I don't understand here is how the events set for `host` in the `NgCheckboxControlDirective` work. Since the host here is the selector for the checkbox component and not the checkbox input itself, it shouldn't trigger any `change` or `blur` event.. but it does.

If you click on the checkbox in the demo linked at the top you'll see that `choosen` changes between `true` and `false`.

Why? Why does clicking on the checkbox fire a `change` event here which then updates the `choosen` state?

The directive which implements `ControlValueAccessor`:

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor , NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngCheckboxControl]',
  host: {'(change)': 'onChange($event.target.checked)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()'},
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: NgCheckboxControlDirective,
      multi: true
}
  ]
})
export class NgCheckboxControlDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

  onChange = (_: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement.firstElementChild, 'checked', value);
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement.firstElementChild, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }
}
```

The checkbox:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-layout',
  template: `
    My checkbox: <input type="checkbox" />
  `,
})
export class CkeckboxLayoutComponent {

  constructor(
    private ngControl: NgControl,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    console.log('... elementRef:', elementRef);
    console.log('... ngControl:', ngControl);
  }

}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
<checkbox-layout formControlName="choosen" ngCheckboxControl></checkbox-layout>
```

Comment: `change` event bubbles. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/wd2zp7Ls/

Comment: You can add `event.stopPropagation()` to stop bubbling. https://jsfiddle.net/nqfxc78e/